# Почему адрес в памяти компьютера нумеруется как 0, 4, 8, 12, а не 0, 1, 2, 3?

Tags: память, архитектура, процессор, адрес, микроархитектура

Читаю книгу Таненбаума "Архитектура компьютера" и наткнулся на такой рисунок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, почему здесь адрес нумеруется как 0, 4, 8, 12, а не 0, 1, 2, 3, если даже снизу написано, что каждый ряд это целое 32-разрядное слово.

То есть, если адреса там нумеруются через 4 единицы, то получается же, что есть и смежные адреса, то есть нумеруется каждый байт, и было бы все логично, если б снизу не было написано, что каждый ряд - это 32-разрядное слово, а если компьютер имеет словесную адресацию, то он просто напросто не должен уметь обращаться к каждому байту.

Comment: Адресация байтовая, а картинка показывает, как могут храниться 32-разрядные слова, их адреса, естественно, идут с шагом 4

Comment: То есть даже если используется термин "слово", адресация не обязательно должна быть словесной? Но тогда в каких случаях можно использовать этот термин, ведь раньше я думал, что слово - это группа байтов, которую процессор может обрабатывать за один раз, то есть размер шины данных будет соответсвовать этому слову.

Comment: Может, только вот адреса тут ни при чём

Comment: `Байт — Минимально адресуемая единица информации` (и он не обязательно восьмибитный), с шиной данных и обработкой слов это не связано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В табличках выше адреса находятся не только в колонке под этим словом, а и во всей таблице. Адреса в колонке являются адресами 32битных слов, а в таблице проадресован каждый байт. То есть адресуются байты, последовательно.

Когда процессоры были восьмибитовые, то процессор обращался непосредственно к каждому байту в памяти. Выглядело это примерно так:

- процессор с восьмибитовой шиной данных и восьми- (мультиплексированной) или шестнадцатибитовой шиной адреса, внутри у него восьмибитовые регистры данных общего назначения и шестнадцатибитовые регистры указателя команд и стека;
- память (ОЗУ) из восьми однобитовых микросхем, подключенных каждая к своему разряду шины данных и к шине адреса;
- память (ПЗУ) из одной (возьмём для простоты) восьмибитовой микросхемы.

Сейчас каждый байт по-прежнему можно адресовать, но работа с памятью происходит словами, размер которых зависит от размера шины данных процессора (в общем случае). Поэтому, если программист захочет прочитать байт по адресу 10, то 32битовый процессор (под картинку) загрузит 4 байта, начиная с адреса 8. Требуемый байт будет третьим в этой четвёрке байтов.

Данные в памяти можно размещать произвольным образом. То есть можно разместить 32битовое слово с адреса 3. Но процессор будет вынужден два раза обратиться к памяти, чтобы прочитать это слово. А слово, которое выровнено по 4ём байтам, процессор получит за одно обращение к памяти. Поэтому компиляторы (по умолчанию) выравнивают данные в памяти по границам слов.

Современные процессоры - это уже целые ЭВМ. Внутри них есть свои процессоры, память и др. устройства. На 64 битовом процессоре работа с восьмибитовыми регистрами, как и с 16, и 32 (возможно, точно не знаю) просто эмулируется.

Comment: `то 32битовый процессор загрузит 4 байта, начиная с адреса 8` А как это проиcходит, куда эти 4 байта загружены?

Comment: @MBo в какой-то регистр, у современных процессоров много служебных регистров.

Comment: Однако mov al, [0xA] запишет в al один байт из адреса 10, mov eax, [0xA] загрузит 4 байта с адресами 10, 11,12,13, movzx eax, BYTEPTR[0xA] - как и первый код, только очистит верх регистра.  На DEC Alpha нужно было адреса выравнивать, так она уже 20 лет как померла.

Comment: @MBo точно, "mov al, [0xA] запишет в al один байт из адреса 10". только прочитает из памяти 8 байтов с адреса 8.

Comment: DEC PDP-11 - это была вещь! Помню, писал программы на БК-0010 прямо в машинных кодах. Простая и удобная система команд и адресации.

Comment: эх, на БК можно было сделать "вирус" из 1 инструкции - записываешь её в начало видеопамяти, передаёшь на неё управление, и она раскрашивает экран в полосатый "матрас", копируя себя саму на всё более верхние адреса памяти.  что-то вроде `MOV (R0)+,(R0)`

Comment: А чтобы она двигалась вниз, начиная с верхних адресов видеопамяти (и затёрла собою всё вплоть до векторов прерываний): `MOV -(PC),-(PC)`.  Строго говоря, архитектура БК была не PDP-11, а LSL-11 (упрощённая версия PDP-11 без инструкции умножения)

Comment: `На DEC Alpha нужно было адреса выравнивать, так она уже 20 лет как померла` - я краем уха слышал, что в ARM-ах до сих пор нужно выравнивать dword-ы на границу 4 байт