# Как организована память компьютера?

Tags: память, архитектура, железо, процессор, байты

В книге Эндрю Таненбаума "Архитектура компьютера" есть такой рисунок, который кажется мне непонятным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще текст перед этим рисунком, чтобы точно было понятно о чем речь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присмотреться на первые два блока, можно увидеть, что символы хранятся в них симметрично, однако когда дело доходит до чисел, симметричность нарушается, почему так?

Ведь по логике цифры должны располагаться следующим образом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это случайно не дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1543069/Почему-адрес-в-памяти-компьютера-нумеруется-как-0-4-8-12-а-не-0-1-2-3

Comment: нет, это другой рисунок

Comment: А с прошлыми темами вы уже разобрались? Ни один ответ не принят.

Comment: Да, разобрался. Ответ только что принял, я новый участник, поэтому многих правил ещё не знаю)

Comment: Вопрос идет практически тот же самый. Если не понят вопрос в прошлом случае то что не понятно? Сама по себе память везде одинаковая. Бывает разная интерпретация последовательности байт процессором при работе с большими числами в качестве большого числа.  Часть платформ считают что младщий байт должен идти первым. А часть платформ считают что слева (первый) должен идти старший байт. И при использовании памяти в качестве "ленты" байт (для хранения) этот момент приходится учитывать.

Comment: Есть разные "форматы" данных. Если в больших числах в формате и в платформе последовательность байт в одинаковом направлении расположена - то перестановка не требуется. Например в bmp формате width height на IBM машине переставлять байты не надо. А png формат использует обратную последовательность и байты в width height приходится переставлять, что бы правильно интрерпретировались цифры. Но выбрав другой процессор - может оказаться наоборот.

Comment: 1) Надписи над рис. `а` и `б` перепутаны местами. Рис. `а` — это прямой порядок следования байтов (big endian), рисунок `б` — это обратный порядок следования байтов (little endian).  2) Когда несколько ячеек памяти интерпретируют как единое большое число, то при прямом порядке байтов наиболее значащие байты числа размещают по меньшим адресам, а при обратном порядке байтов наиболее значащие байты размещают по большим адресам. На рисунке младший байт четырёхбайтового целого числа `21` хранится по адресу `15` при прямом порядке и по адресу `12` при обратном порядке. Вот почему симметрия нарушена.

Answer (score 0):

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) про порядок байтов хорошо написано. Вы уже как-то поучитесь находить ответы - на такие общие вопросы они обязательно найдутся. Что касается иллюстраций, то они с ошибками, про это уже написали. Помню, как-то приятель попросил меня сделать для него курсовик по транспортной задаче. Я взял очень уважаемую книгу - Справочник по высшей математике Корнов. Транспортная задача там изложена на одной страничке. Так вот, я нашёл там 14(!) ошибок.

Из изложенного вам просто нужно понимать, что существует вариативность в расположении частей данных в многобайтовых последовательностях. Поэтому, если вдруг вы падёте так низко :-), до уровня байтов, то нужно обращаться к документации.

Как написано в статье по ссылке,

> Этот (big endian) порядок является стандартным для протоколов TCP/IP, он используется в заголовках пакетов данных и во многих протоколах более высокого уровня, разработанных для использования поверх TCP/IP.

То есть читаете, например, описание протокола TCP/IP, и выясняете там порядок расположения байтов.